# context problems at the activity in the library

Tags: android, logging, android-toast

When I start a new activity in my library project, this activity seems like having context problems, doesn't make a toast for instance.

Here is my log

```
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at com.companymobile.companycorelibrary.data.smartsync.SmartSyncDataBaseHelper.getLastUpdate(SmartSyncDataBaseHelper.java:292)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at com.companymobile.companycorelibrary.data.smartsync.SmartSyncManager.getActivities(SmartSyncManager.java:213)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at com.companymobile.companyviewlibrary.activities.EventsActivity.onCreate(EventsActivity.java:60)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
05-20 09:59:41.340: W/System.err(4624):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624): com.novoda.location.exception.NoProviderAvailable
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at com.novoda.location.LocationUpdateManager.startActiveLocationUpdates(LocationUpdateManager.java:50)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at com.novoda.location.DefaultLocator.startListeningForLocationUpdates(DefaultLocator.java:128)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at com.novoda.location.DefaultLocator.startActiveLocationUpdates(DefaultLocator.java:94)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at com.companymobile.companyviewlibrary.activities.EventsActivity.onResume(EventsActivity.java:118)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1157)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4543)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1998)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
05-20 09:59:41.370: W/System.err(4624):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my main project which will call library activity.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.companymobile.companyviewlibrary.activities.EventsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

This is my library activity.

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("SmartSyncManager", ""+"create");
```

when new activity starts, I can see its layout  but not logs and toasts.
 I have tried `getApplicationContext()`, `EventsActivity.this getBaseContext()`, yet none could solve the situation.

Comment: i already have tried EventsActivity.this.and also 'this'. it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the activity to pass through to the Toast function. So either try

```
Toast.makeText(this, "create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(EventsActivity.this, "create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Perhaps the line: `super.onCreate(null);` is incorrect, and the bundle should be parsed to it.

Comment: i have changed to super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and also used code you recommended. But it didn't work

Comment: same old as my log above.

Comment: The error logs aren't relating to the showing of toasts, its relating to finding a location provider - I think something else is causing the issue.

Comment: you are right , lacking of permissions in the anifest file for the locations causing this.